# Room API - How to retrieve recently inserted generated id of the entity?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I need to retrieve the generated `id` value of an entity which is recently inserted as the code sample added below demonstrates:

As mentioned above, the `id` field  of the entity `Student` is annotated with `PrimaryKey(autoGenerate= true)`.

```
Student s = new Student();
s.setName("foo");
// call of other setters
appDatabase.getGenericDAO().insertStudent(s);
// Now I need to retrieve the value of generated id as we do in Hibernate by the usage of merge method
Integer id = s.getId();
```

DAO

```
@Dao
public interface IGenericDAO {

    @Insert
    Long insertStudent(Student student);

    @Insert
    void insertOgrenci(List<Student> studentList);

    @Update
    void updateOgrenci(Ogrenci... ogrenci);

    @Delete
    void deleteOgrenci(Ogrenci... ogrenci); 

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have your `@Insert` method return a `long`:

```
@Insert
long insertStudent(Student s);
```

The return value will be the `rowId` of the row, and that should be the auto-generated primary key value.

Comment: @talha06: So... what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that `s.getId()` returns `null`.

Comment: @talha06: So... put the `Long` that you get from the `Student` into the `Student`.

Comment: is the "rowId" is primary key always?

Comment: @GkMohammadEmon: No, you can define your own primary key. However, SQLite always adds a unique row ID, regardless of whether you use it as your primary key or not.

Comment: So what is the best approach if i want to get the primary key of my latest inserted value? @CommonsWare

Comment: @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) this is added to my entity. So does it return me the primary key to it?

Comment: @GkMohammadEmon: IIRC, yes. The auto-generated primary key should be the row ID and is what a single-entity `insert()` would return.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is it guaranteed that an autogenerated primary key, the rowid and the value returned by an insert are identical? I have not seen that in the documentation.

Comment: @JulianSymes: AFAIK, `insert()` returns the value that SQLite exposes [via `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html). Quoting those docs, " Each entry in most SQLite tables (except for WITHOUT ROWID tables) has a unique 64-bit signed integer key called the "rowid". The rowid is always available as an undeclared column named ROWID, OID, or _ROWID_ as long as those names are not also used by explicitly declared columns. If the table has a column of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY then that column is another alias for the rowid."